# Convert secp256k1 private key to sr25519 private key

Tags: elliptic-curves, secp256k1

Is it possible to convert secp256k1 private key to valid sr25519 key?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is it possible to convert secp256k1 private key to valid sr25519 key?

**Yes**. It's possible to convert any secret piece of data to private or secret key of any cryptosystem, by using that piece of data as seed of a deterministic key generator for said destination cryptosystem. And it's reasonable to do so when there is enough entropy in the source data, including in the case in point since a secp256k1 private key has nearly 256 bits of entropy, when sr25519 is content with a little above 252. Looking at it's spec, it looks like [GenPrivKeyFromSecret](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/tendermint/tendermint/crypto/sr25519#GenPrivKey) would do, irrespective of the format of the source key.

---

Absent a stated purpose, it's hard to be more precise. And it's uncertain the whole endeavor serves a useful purpose. It goes against a common recommendation that I rephrase as:

> one use, one key

where you can change *use* to usage, purpose, website, device… and *key* to secret, secret key, private key, passphrase, password, PIN…

Comment: I also included the description of bit clamping, the fact that the public key is not compatible and that you might want to use a KDF (although `GenPrivKeyFromSecret` already does that using SHA-512 basically: see [here](https://github.com/oasisprotocol/curve25519-voi/blob/9075215235b7831a986762f57a46351c473c22b5/primitives/sr25519/keys.go)) in an answer that I was writing. Do you have any idea why SHA-512 is used instead of SHA-256 in that library?

Comment: @MaartenBodewes : Yes, I (now) see your nice deleted answer. I think using SHA-512 has to do with Ed25519 [traditionally](https://ed25519.cr.yp.to/ed25519-20110926.pdf#page=8) using SHA-512 as a PRF to generate pseudorandom scalars multiplying group elements, with optional reduction modulo prime $\ell=2^{252}+27742317777372353535851937790883648493$ or multiple thereof, in the interest of parameterizable resistance to side-channel attacks.